# pass variable between functions in same controller

Tags: php, variables, cakephp

```
class AppointmentsController extends AppController {
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Appointment->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid appointment'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Appointment.' . $this->Appointment->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('appointment', $this->Appointment->find('first', $options));

    $kk = $this->Appointment->find('first',  array('fields' => 'status', 'conditions' => array('Appointment.id' => $id)));
    $ss = reset($kk);
    $stats = reset($ss);
}
}
```

I have set $stats via getting value from DB and i want to use in in another function in same controller

then I want to use like this

```
class AppointmentsController extends AppController {
function confirm(){
$stats = 'New';

}
}
```

Comment: have you looked at class variables/properties? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that it's the same class, have you tried using `$this->stats` instead of a local variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can call another function in your first function like

```
$this->confirm($status); // calling confirm function

function confirm($status)
{
 //use status as you want
}
```

Or you can set status as global variable then this can you accessible in any function.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you've to create function in the model that will return the value of the field by id.

```
<?php
// model/AppModel.php

public function getFieldById($field='id', $id){
  return $this->field($field, array('id' => $id));
}


// in controller function you can access this like.

$status = $this->Appointment->getFieldById('status', $id); // $id will be appointment id.

?>
```